# How to check if point geometry from table 1 exist to line geometry from table 2 in spatial sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, spatial-query, utm

I have two tables, table 1 is valve - POINT geometry
table 2 is tbline - LINE geometry. I need to get the valve_id from valve if valve.geometry exists in tbline.geometry and I need to identify which point do valve_id positioned its either startpoint or EndPoint?
Any help is much appreciated. Currently, this is my query, I'm stuck here:

```sql
;WITH CTE_A AS (
    select a.valve_id, a.elevation,geometry from valve a 
)
Select
b.valve_id as startnode,B.elevation from tblline C INNER JOIN CTE_A B  ON c.geometry.STStartPoint().STTouches(B.geometry) = 1 
union
SELECT b.valve_id as endnode,b.elevation from tblline d INNER JOIN CTE_A B  ON d.geometry.STEndPoint().STTouches(B.geometry) = 1
```

Here's my expected output:
[expected result][1]

table - valve

| valve_id | PointX | PointY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VLV873 | 533726.788191639 | 1030389.94089809 |
| VLV289 | 533726.403676326 | 1030390.12088887 |

table - tblline

| StartX | StartY | EndX | EndY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 533726.788191639 | 1030389.94089809 | 533726.403676326 | 1030390.12088887 |

below is my expected result in which I need to update this to tblline start_node and end_node column:

| startnode | endnode |
| --- | --- |
| VLV873 | VLV289 |

Comment: Can you supply sample data.  Also spatial data coordinates are stored as floating point values, so to determine if two shapes touch, it's typically necessary to buffer to create a tolerance.

Comment: hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added sample data.

Comment: Thank you, how to get the endnode @DavidBrowne-Microsoft?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: what I expected results are 
|start node|start elevation|end node|end elevation

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinates are stored with limited precision it's often impractical to determine of two shapes "touch".  Instead select a small buffer distance and test if they overlap.  So "touching" is replaced by "within 0.001 units" or somesuch.  eg

```
use tempdb

drop table if exists valve
drop table if exists tblline
go
create table valve(valve_id varchar(20) primary key, elevation float default 0, geometry geometry)
create table tblline (id int identity primary key, geometry geometry)

insert into valve(valve_id, geometry) 
    values ('VLV873', geometry::Point(533726.788191639, 1030389.94089809,0))
insert into valve(valve_id, geometry) 
    values ('VLV289', geometry::Point(533726.403676326, 1030390.12088887,0))

insert into tblline(geometry) 
    values (geometry::STLineFromText('LINESTRING (533726.788191639 1030389.94089809, 533726.403676326 1030390.12088887)',0))
--visualize the results
select geometry.STBuffer(0.001) from tblline
union all
select geometry.STBuffer(0.02) from valve 

go

;WITH CTE_A AS (
    select a.valve_id, a.elevation,geometry from valve a 
)
Select b.valve_id as startnode,B.elevation 
from tblline C 
INNER JOIN CTE_A B  
  ON c.geometry.STStartPoint().STBuffer(0.001).STIntersects(B.geometry) = 1 
union
SELECT b.valve_id as endnode,b.elevation 
from tblline d 
INNER JOIN CTE_A B  
    ON d.geometry.STEndPoint().STBuffer(0.001).STIntersects(B.geometry) = 1
```

outputs

[image]

and

```
startnode            elevation
-------------------- ----------------------
VLV289               0
VLV873               0

(2 rows affected)
```